# ¿Como encontrar el ultimo registro capturado de cada vendedor en SQL?

Tags: postgresql

Espero puedan ayudarme, quiero encontrar en POSTGRE SQL el ultimo registro capturado por cada vendedor de la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea es que el filtro se aplique de la siguente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano les agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta se entiende muy bien gracias al esfuerzo que has realizado detallando el resultado al que querías llegar. Aunque, para que te resulte útil, tanto a ti como a la comunidad, debes aportar los intentos que has realizado. No podemos ayudarte a mejorar si no vemos en qué te equivocas.

Como se trata de una combinación por dos campos tras un agrupamiento para obtener máximos, te adelanto la solución. Pero, por favor, indica qué partes son las que más cuestan entender para ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación.

```
select * from tabla join (
  select vendedor,
    max(fecha) fecha
    from tabla
    group by 1
  ) c1 using(fecha,vendedor)
  order by 1 desc;
```

Te dejo un fiddle para las pruebas:
https://dbfiddle.uk/3LaShTn1

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tendré en cuenta tus comentarios, para este ejercicio intentaba usar la clausula DISTINCT y funciones ventana pero me omitía resultados o no me daba la info que necesitaba, no se me ocurrio usar una subconsulta dentro del join, muchas gracias nuevamente por tu ayuda.